# Filter geography column in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, geospatial, shapes, geography

I'm looking around for any answer which I could for my purpose but I'm not able to find it, so I've decided to submit a question.

I have several tables with geography type fields inside and i need to define a where clause for finding all the records within an ellipse.

My ellipse properties are: `minoraxis, majoraxis, point` and `rotation`. I already have the where clause which look for a geography inside a circle shape. It's something like this:

```
select * 
from locations 
where shape.STIntersects(geography::STPointFromText('POINT(32.113, -81.3225)', 4326).STBuffer(10)) = 1
```

How could I do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it within a specific ellipse? If so, is it that you're having a hard time defining a geography instance that represents that ellipse?

Comment: @BenThul there are several instances shapes in the project, users can defined one of them for list entities with their location within or equal to their defined shape. My problem is I don't know how could create a where clauses like which one described before for circle shape.